# How do I get min/max on a mesh

Tags: opengl, java, lwjgl, mesh, obj

I am trying to create an AABB but I need to know how to store min/max from a mesh.

Here is my code(I got it from thin matrix) :

```
package com.chimpro.london.objLoader;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector2f;
import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector3f;

import com.chimpro.london.MainComp;
import com.chimpro.london.gfx.Loader;
import com.chimpro.london.models.TexturedModel;

public class OBJFileLoader {

public static TexturedModel loadOBJ(String objFileName,String textureLoc) throws IOException {
    InputStreamReader fis = new InputStreamReader(MainComp.class.getResourceAsStream(objFileName));
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fis);
    String line;
    List<Vertex> vertices = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
    List<Vector2f> textures = new ArrayList<Vector2f>();
    List<Vector3f> normals = new ArrayList<Vector3f>();
    List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    try {
        while (true) {
            line = reader.readLine();
            if (line.startsWith("v ")) {
                String[] currentLine = line.split(" ");
                Vector3f vertex = new Vector3f((float) Float.valueOf(currentLine[1]),
                        (float) Float.valueOf(currentLine[2]),
                        (float) Float.valueOf(currentLine[3]));
                Vertex newVertex = new Vertex(vertices.size(), vertex);
                vertices.add(newVertex);

            } else if (line.startsWith("vt ")) {
                String[] currentLine = line.split(" ");
                Vector2f texture = new Vector2f((float) Float.valueOf(currentLine[1]),
                        (float) Float.valueOf(currentLine[2]));
                textures.add(texture);
            } else if (line.startsWith("vn ")) {
                String[] currentLine = line.split(" ");
                Vector3f normal = new Vector3f((float) Float.valueOf(currentLine[1]),
                        (float) Float.valueOf(currentLine[2]),
                        (float) Float.valueOf(currentLine[3]));
                normals.add(normal);
            } else if (line.startsWith("f ")) {
                break;
            }
        }
        while (line != null && line.startsWith("f ")) {
            String[] currentLine = line.split(" ");
            String[] vertex1 = currentLine[1].split("/");
            String[] vertex2 = currentLine[2].split("/");
            String[] vertex3 = currentLine[3].split("/");
            processVertex(vertex1, vertices, indices);
            processVertex(vertex2, vertices, indices);
            processVertex(vertex3, vertices, indices);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error reading the file");
    }
    removeUnusedVertices(vertices);
    float[] verticesArray = new float[vertices.size() * 3];
    float[] texturesArray = new float[vertices.size() * 2];
    float[] normalsArray = new float[vertices.size() * 3];
    float furthest = convertDataToArrays(vertices, textures, normals, verticesArray,
            texturesArray, normalsArray);
    int[] indicesArray = convertIndicesListToArray(indices);
    TexturedModel model = new TexturedModel(Loader.loadToVao(verticesArray, texturesArray, normalsArray, indicesArray),0,vertices,furthest, textureLoc);
    return model;

}

private static void processVertex(String[] vertex, List<Vertex> vertices, List<Integer> indices) {
    int index = Integer.parseInt(vertex[0]) - 1;
    Vertex currentVertex = vertices.get(index);
    int textureIndex = Integer.parseInt(vertex[1]) - 1;
    int normalIndex = Integer.parseInt(vertex[2]) - 1;
    if (!currentVertex.isSet()) {
        currentVertex.setTextureIndex(textureIndex);
        currentVertex.setNormalIndex(normalIndex);
        indices.add(index);
    } else {
        dealWithAlreadyProcessedVertex(currentVertex, textureIndex, normalIndex, indices,
                vertices);
    }
}

private static int[] convertIndicesListToArray(List<Integer> indices) {
    int[] indicesArray = new int[indices.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < indicesArray.length; i++) {
        indicesArray[i] = indices.get(i);
    }
    return indicesArray;
}

private static float convertDataToArrays(List<Vertex> vertices, List<Vector2f> textures,
        List<Vector3f> normals, float[] verticesArray, float[] texturesArray,
        float[] normalsArray) {
    float furthestPoint = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++) {
        Vertex currentVertex = vertices.get(i);
        if (currentVertex.getLength() > furthestPoint) {
            furthestPoint = currentVertex.getLength();
        }
        Vector3f position = currentVertex.getPosition();
        Vector2f textureCoord = textures.get(currentVertex.getTextureIndex());
        Vector3f normalVector = normals.get(currentVertex.getNormalIndex());
        verticesArray[i * 3] = position.x;
        verticesArray[i * 3 + 1] = position.y;
        verticesArray[i * 3 + 2] = position.z;
        texturesArray[i * 2] = textureCoord.x;
        texturesArray[i * 2 + 1] = 1 - textureCoord.y;
        normalsArray[i * 3] = normalVector.x;
        normalsArray[i * 3 + 1] = normalVector.y;
        normalsArray[i * 3 + 2] = normalVector.z;
    }
    return furthestPoint;
}

private static void dealWithAlreadyProcessedVertex(Vertex previousVertex, int newTextureIndex,
        int newNormalIndex, List<Integer> indices, List<Vertex> vertices) {
    if (previousVertex.hasSameTextureAndNormal(newTextureIndex, newNormalIndex)) {
        indices.add(previousVertex.getIndex());
    } else {
        Vertex anotherVertex = previousVertex.getDuplicateVertex();
        if (anotherVertex != null) {
            dealWithAlreadyProcessedVertex(anotherVertex, newTextureIndex, newNormalIndex,
                    indices, vertices);
        } else {
            Vertex duplicateVertex = new Vertex(vertices.size(), previousVertex.getPosition());
            duplicateVertex.setTextureIndex(newTextureIndex);
            duplicateVertex.setNormalIndex(newNormalIndex);
            previousVertex.setDuplicateVertex(duplicateVertex);
            vertices.add(duplicateVertex);
            indices.add(duplicateVertex.getIndex());
        }

    }
}

private static void removeUnusedVertices(List<Vertex> vertices){
    for(Vertex vertex:vertices){
        if(!vertex.isSet()){
            vertex.setTextureIndex(0);
            vertex.setNormalIndex(0);
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Create two Vector3f variables to store the min and max corners respectively, then just loop through your vertices and set the x,y and z components as necessary using min/max functions.

Comment: What have you tried and what went wrong? Also I would recommend removing the parts of the code that is not relevant to your question.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt the tutorial I use didn't show how to calculate min/max

Comment: Well, how would _you_ calculate the min/max? If you're to develop games, you have to keep in mind that not everything is taught in tutorials.

Comment: If you're having trouble doing things like this, I recommend starting out more basic and learning what you are writing is actually doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same solution as Macky ben Jonah's but a little neater:

```
private static Vector3f getExtreme(final List<Vertex> vertices,
        final BinaryOperator<Float> op) {
    final float x = vertices.stream().map(v -> v.getPosition().x).reduce(op).orElse(0f);
    final float y = vertices.stream().map(v -> v.getPosition().y).reduce(op).orElse(0f);
    final float z = vertices.stream().map(v -> v.getPosition().z).reduce(op).orElse(0f);
    return new Vector3f(x, y, z);
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
Vector3f min = getExtreme(vertices, Math::min);
Vector3f max = getExtreme(vertices, Math::max);
```

This requires Java 8 because it makes use of [Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) and it is also a lot more performance friendly than the original solution since it does not have to create new lists and loop through them every time it is called.

Comment: would it work for java 9

Comment: @MackybenJonah Yes, Java is 100% (or close enough) backwards compatible so this will work for all java version >= 8.

Comment: Try running this code on a java debugger. I'm getting an error. `Stream has already been operated on or closed`. It is an illegal state exception. For a reference see my code [above](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/155425/113516).

Comment: @MackybenJonah My bad. Just change `steam` to `vertices.stream()` (I edited my answer).

Answer (score 4):

Set each component of the initial `maximum` coordinate to the *minimum* value of a float. Similarly, set each component of the initial `minimum` to the *maximum* value of a float.

Iterate over every vertex in the mesh. With each vertex, set the `maximum`, component-wise, to the larger of the current `maximum` or the current vertex. Similarly, for the `minimum`, set it component-wise to the smaller of the current maximum or the vertex.

In pseudo-code, this might look like:

```
Vector minimum(Float.Maximum, Float.Maximum, Float.Maximum);
Vector maximum(Float.Minimum, Float.Minimum, Float.Minimum);
foreach(Vertex vertex in mesh) {
  minimum = componentwiseMinimum(minimum, vertex.position);
  maximum = componentwiseMaximum(maximum, vertex.position);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is my solution:**

```
    private static Vector3f min(List<Vertex> vertices) {
    List<Float>  xArray= new ArrayList<>();
    List<Float> yArray = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Float> zArray = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Vertex vertex : vertices) {
        xArray.add(vertex.getPosition().x);
        yArray.add(vertex.getPosition().y);
        zArray.add(vertex.getPosition().z);
    }
    return new Vector3f(Collections.min(xArray),Collections.min(yArray),Collections.min(zArray));
}

private static Vector3f max(List<Vertex> vertices) {
    List<Float>  xArray= new ArrayList<>();
    List<Float> yArray = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Float> zArray = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Vertex vertex : vertices) {
        xArray.add(vertex.getPosition().x);
        yArray.add(vertex.getPosition().y);
        zArray.add(vertex.getPosition().z);
    }
    return new Vector3f(Collections.max(xArray),Collections.max   (yArray),Collections.max(zArray));
}
```

Comment: While this approach will work (it's doing everything you need it to), it's not very _efficient_. You're creating a total of six new array objects (you don't need to create any) and you're looping through arrays eight times (you only need to loop through the vertices array once).